# How to abbreviate the "trim" option of an image in a \newcommand?

Tags: graphics, crop

I apologize if my question is worded incorrectly, please feel free to modify it.

I have a long document with many figures, most of which need to be trimmed at the same lengths. I would like to abbreviate the trim values so I don't have to type the numbers every time, and to make it easier to edit them in the future without scrolling through the entire document.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\crops}{2mm 2mm 2mm 2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
% \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth,clip=true,trim=2mm 2mm 2mm 2mm]{example.png} % (works)
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth,clip=true,trim=\crops]{example.png} % (does not work)
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can find the example image I used [here](http://domaingang.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/example.png)

This document yields an error:
File ended while scanning use of \Gread@parse@vp

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: This may be a problem of expanding order. One could try to add \expandafter before the \includegraphics. Alternatively, one could define a command \cropincludegraphics of which the parameters are handed to an includegraphics with proper crops.

Comment: @JFMeier Thank you. The \cropincludegraphics works too, but I prefer the new key method in the answer since it doesn't require me to change all the figures include command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a new key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{mycrops}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=2mm 2mm 2mm 2mm,clip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

With cropping

\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth,mycrops]{example-image-a.png}

Without cropping

\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}
\end{document}
```

[image]